# How to measure elapsed CPU time of JS code execution in Node.js for benchmarking?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cpu-usage, microbenchmark

I have a function that does simple performance benchmarking of arbitrary JS function invocation like this:

```
function benchmark(f) {
   var startTime = Date.now();
   f();
   var endTime = Date.now();
   console.log('Elapsed: %d ms', endTime - startTime);
}
```

The functions that I test with it take typically 2-5s to execute, so the overhead of counting one full call to Date.now() is negligible.

Nevertheless, the benchmark times vary quite considerably based on what other processes happen to be running on my machine, so even if I run the benchmark several times and take the smallest value I can still see variations of 20-50% between between successive (sets of) runs—even when the machine is "mostly" idle.  This makes it difficult to see performance changes of <5%.

I end up having to watch Activity Monitor and wait until the system looks (mostly) idle, then hope that nothing else starts up in the middle of the run.  I'd like, instead, to modify the benchmark to measure elapsed CPU time instead of elapsed wall time.  This should make it mostly insensitive to being blocked on I/O and considerably less sensitive to CPU contention (though not insensitive: due to hyper-threading I expect that if the number of runnable threads exceeds the number of physical CPU cores that the apparent performance will decrease as hyper-threads contend for actual hardware).

How can I query the elapsed CPU time of the `node` process from within Node?

Comment: I suppose the strategy may depend on what those functions do. If they are just idle for some period of time, you could mock timer and make them synchronous. And https://www.npmjs.com/package/benchmark is well-suited for JS benchmarks. *Nevertheless, the benchmark times vary quite considerably based on what other processes happen to be running on my machine* - doesn't sound good. If you have processes that can really affect benchmark results, it's quite pointless. Shut them down if you can.

Comment: why not use console.time('function f ') f() console.timeEnd('function f ') to get the execution time

Comment: @BittuS Because that has the exact same problem that OP's current code has. It doesn't measure CPU time.

Comment: @estus: the code I am benchmarking is 100% synchronous and does ~no I/O, so never idle.  It's also deterministic, so successive runs without code changes should use near-constant amounts of CPU time.  I could use `time node benchmark.js` to get elapsed CPU time, but I don't want to count startup/setup time.

Background processes include my editor, web browser, macOS system processes, etc., all of which are unavoidable when doing development but which rarely average more than 0.25 CPU.  Absent hyperthreading, elapsed CPU time for node should be insensitive to contention.

Comment: You can obviously exit editor and web browser if you believe they could contribute. https://www.npmjs.com/package/benchmark allows to get statistically significant results.

Comment: @estus: True—though the editor is also the IDE from which I run the tests, and while tests can be run without it it makes the edit/bench cycle take rather longer if I have to keep quitting and restarting it.  The bigger problem are system background tasks like `mds_stores`, `puppet` and other things which run intermittently and outside of my control.

Comment: It depends on what sort of this load is and how much is it. 1-2% won't make a difference. Since there are multiple cores and Node is single-threaded, you could expect that the load will be distributed among the cores. You could run Node with higher priority, for starters.